# Generating variations with bash

Tags: bash

Looking for en nicer solution for the next code:

```
for i in a b c
do
  for j in A B C
  do
    for k in 1 2 3
    do
      echo "$i$j$k"
    done
  done
done
```

Sure is here some simpler solution.

Comment: What are you trying to output?

Comment: exactlty that, what the script does - but it is ugly..

Comment: It does 27 iterations and prints the output as below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bit simpler

```
echo {a,b,c}{A,B,C}{1,2,3}
```

or if want one per line, so

```
echo {a,b,c}{A,B,C}{1,2,3} | xargs -n1
```

BTW, you can use the above bracer expansion for example saving keyboard typing for example when need make backup files, like:

```
cp /some/long/path/And_very-ugly-fileName{,.copy}
```

will make the `/some/long/path/And_very-ugly-fileName.copy` without second filename typing.

Comment: +1. If you want 1 per line: `printf "%s\n" {a,b,c}{A,B,C}{1,2,3}`

Answer (score 6):

Use a [**brace expansion**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
echo {a,b,c}{A,B,C}{1,2,3}
```

This will print **all** possible combinations between the sets `{a,b,c}`, `{A,B,C}`, and `{1,2,3}`.

Or even simpler, using ranges:

```
echo {a..c}{A..C}{1..3}
```

And if you want to print each combination per line, use a `for`-loop:

```
for i in {a..c}{A..C}{1..3}; do echo $i; done
```